# I facing an error while working with 'cloudinary' , to upload images , for my MERN stack project

Tags: node.js, express, es6-modules, cloudinary

I am following this youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rw_QeJLnCK4 , which step by step guides on how to upload an image to cloudinary.

this is the cloudinary config -

[image]

```
router.post('/create',auth,createBlog)
```

this is the route at which i am handling image upload

And here in the createBlog controller , i am importing that cloudinary config and doing the same as mentioned in the youtube video -

[image]

I am able to get the bas64encoded string of the image in the **'req.body.image'** which i sent from frontend.

But the **console.log(response)** gives me this error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'upload' of undefined
```

I have also created a preset named 'my_blogwebsite' in cloudinary associated with the folder of the same name.

I am using ES6 module for importing and exporting instead of commonJS in my express app.And in the video the instructor requires the cloudinary in commonJS like this -

```
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
```

But i dont know how to add that '.v2' in ES6 module.I tried searching on google about this but had no luck.I think achieving this will solve my issue but i am not sure.

Edit - This is my folder structure

[image]

Please help me resolve this , thank you

Comment: Does it work if you replace `cloudinary.uploader.upload` with `cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload`?

Comment: I tried adding what you mentioned and this is the error i got - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploader' of undefined`

Comment: What is the path on your system where the Cloudinary module is installed? By default, you should be able to import it from `./node_modules/cloudinary/cloudinary.js`

Comment: @Aleksandar the path is the same as you wrote.

Comment: In that case, did you update the import path in your config (first screenshot)?

Comment: no i didnt , it's the same as shown in screenshot

Comment: What is the path of your config file? Based on that in relation to the node_modules folder you should be able to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: @Aleksandar I added a screenshot of my folder structure.The cloudinary config resides in cloudinary.js under utils folder

Comment: Could you try updating the line `import cloudinary from 'cloudinary';` to `import cloudinary from '../node_modules/cloudinary/cloudinary.js;`

Comment: didnt helped , it again showed the - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'upload' of undefined`.Also when i hover my mouse on `import cloudinary from '../node_modules/cloudinary/cloudinary.js'` , it says - `could not find a declaration file for module`

Answer (score 1):

you can import it this way:

```
import {v2 as cloudinary} from "cloudinary"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
import cloudinaryModule from "cloudibary";

const cloudinaryModule = cloudinaryModule.v2;
```

Answer (score 0):

cloudinary config file

```
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()
import { v2 } from "cloudinary"

v2.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
})

export default v2
```